# Checking if an array is in a correct order

Tags: c#

How would I be able to check that the array `game` is in equal order to the sorted array of `positions`?
The array should be in the order:
`2A, 2B, 2C, 0, 1A, 1B, 1C` for the user to be successful

```
public static void Maincode()
{
    string[] game = { "1A", "1B", "1C", "0", "2A", "2B", "2C" };
    string[] positions = new string[]
    {
        "2A",
        "2B",
        "2C",
        "0",
        "1A",
        "1B",
        "1C",

    };
    // other code
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "is in equal order"? Do you mean that the `game` array needs to be the same as the `positions` array for success? What have you tried? Does simply checking if the `i`th element of `game` is equal to the `i`th element of `positions` not work for you?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you could use `SequenceEqual` from `System.Linq` to compare if two sequences are equal like that:

```
game.SequenceEqual(positions) // returns true if sequences are in the same order, otherwise false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use *Enumerable.SequenceEqual*. Or if you wish to practice or make your own algorithm, then try to loop through elements of an array and compare if the elements on current position are equal:

```
for(int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
{
   if(!game[i].Equals(positions[i])
     Console.WriteLine("Not Equal!");
}
```